# Create column of data frames based on function

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I would like to use the `map` function with the `tidyverse` to create a column of data frames based on arguments from some, but not all, of the columns of the original data frame/tibble.

I would prefer to be able to use the `map` function so that I can replace this with `future_map` to utilize parallel computing.

**With the exception of this solution *not* using `map`**, this solution produces the correct end result (see also this question and answer: [How to use rowwise to create a list column based on a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69051067/how-to-use-rowwise-to-create-a-list-column-based-on-a-function/69051080#69051080)):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)

df <- data.frame(a= c(1,2,3), b=c(2,3,4), c=c(6,5,8))

fun <- function(q,y) {
    r <- data.frame(col1 = c(q+y, q, q, y), col2 = c(q,q,q,y))
    r
}

result1 <- df %>% rowwise(a) %>% mutate(list1 = list(fun(a, b)))

> result1
# A tibble: 3 × 4
# Rowwise:  a
      a     b     c list1       
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list>      
1     1     2     6 <df [4 × 2]>
2     2     3     5 <df [4 × 2]>
3     3     4     8 <df [4 × 2]>
```

How can I instead do this with `map`? Here are three incorrect attempts:

Incorrect attempt 1:

```
wrong1 <- df %>% mutate(list1 = map(list(a,b), fun))
```

Incorrect attempt 2:

```
wrong2 <- df %>% mutate(list1 = map(c(a,b), fun))
```

Incorrect attempt 2:

```
wrong3 <- df %>% mutate(list1 = list(map(list(a,b), fun)))
```

The error I get is `x argument "y" is missing, with no default`. And I am not sure how to pass multiple arguments into a situation like this.

I would like a solution with multiple arguments, but if that is not possible, let's move to a function with one argument.

```
fun_one_arg <- function(q) {
    r <- data.frame(col1 = c(q, q, q, q+q), col2 = c(3*q,q,q,q/2))
    r
}

wrong4 <- df %>% mutate(list1 = map(a, fun_one_arg))
wrong5 <- df %>% mutate(list1 = list(map(a, fun_one_arg)))
```

These run, but the fourth columns are not data frames, as I would have expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map2` as there are two arguments

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(list1 = map2(a, b, fun)) %>%
    as_tibble
# A tibble: 3 x 4
      a     b     c list1       
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list>      
1     1     2     6 <df [4 × 2]>
2     2     3     5 <df [4 × 2]>
3     3     4     8 <df [4 × 2]>
```

Or another option is `pmap` which can take more than 2 columns as well.  The `..1`, `..2` represents the columns in the same order

```
df %>%
    mutate(list1 = pmap(across(c(a, b)), ~ fun(..1, ..2))) %>%
    as_tibble
```

Comment: Surely you have answered a duplicate question in the past.

Comment: Thanks! A couple questions, if you don't mind: For the first solution, why does `list` show up as (for the first row) `3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2` instead of `<df [4 × 2]>` as in the `rowwise` solution? And for the second solution, I am getting the error: `Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `list1`.
ℹ `list1 = pmap(across(c(a, b)), fun)`.
x unused arguments (a = .l[[1]][[i]], b = .l[[2]][[i]])`

Comment: @bill999 `df` input is a data.frame and thus it returns a data.frame.  In `rowwise`, it adds the attributes and create the `tibble`

Comment: I updated the post.  Now both of them gives the same output